# R: Tossing a fair coin 500 times and computing the probability in following case

Tags: r

How can i approximate the probability that the proportion of heads obtained will be between 0.5 and 0.52 when a fair coin is tossed 500 times?

What i can do so far to compute  head in 500 trials

```
  a=rbinom(500,size=1,prob=.5)
```

Comment: since this looks like homework, just some hints: `a>=(0.5*500) & a<=(0.52*500)`; `?replicate`

Comment: Have you thought about the variance of that estimation method under those sampling conditions? You are only going to be getting 0.02*500 = 10 events. (Still replying under the assumptions this is HW.)